# Symfony /sitemap.xml route inaccessible

Tags: php, symfony, sitemap

In a symfony 5 app, i have a route `@Route("/sitemap.xml", name="sitemap", defaults={"_format"="xml"})`
When i try to access this route, symfony look for the sitemap file, not the route.
How can i force the route call, not the file?
My controller :

```
class SitemapController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/sitemap.xml", name="sitemap", defaults={"_format"="xml"})
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
     $urls = [];
     ...
        $response = new Response(
            $this->renderView('sitemap/index.html.twig', ['urls' => $urls,
                'hostname' => $hostname]),
            200
        );
        
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        
        return $response;
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do this, i hope it works for you.

```
    /**
     * @Route("/sitemap.xml", name="sitemap", defaults={"_format"="xml"})
     */
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        // We get the hostname from the URL
        $hostname = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();

        // Urls List
        $urls = [];
        // Urls statiques
        $urls[] = ['loc' => $this->generateUrl('index')];
        $urls[] = ['loc' => $this->generateUrl('commercial')];
        $urls[] = ['loc' => $this->generateUrl('residential')];
        $urls[] = ['loc' => $this->generateUrl('contact')];

        $response = new Response(
            $this->renderView('sitemap/index.html.twig', [
                'urls' => $urls,
                'hostname' => $hostname,
            ]),
            200
        );
        // Adding headers 
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        // Send the response
        return $response;
    }
```